# move button down on collapse expand

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have the code to make my list drop down and back up. Now I want the button to go along with it both ways. I managed to get it down, but back up not so good. I was trying to add the button in a common div with the list, but it did not work because the button disappeared after clicked on time. So I really want to make it as stylistic as possible, it would be great to add a slowmotion effect and loading effect if possible.

here is the code again

Html

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#">Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 20</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#right-column-sidebar{
    position: absolute; 
    right: -140px;
}

div#right-column-sidebar ol{
    position:absolute; 
    right: 150px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    list-style-type:none
}

div#right-column-sidebar ol li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0; 
    border-bottom: 1px dotted grey; 
    width: 200px; display: block;
}

div#right-column-sidebar ol li a{
    font-size: 60%; color: blue;margin-left: 20px
}
div#right-column-sidebar ol li:nth-child(11){
    margin-left:0;
}      
div#right-column-sidebar ol li a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a.button {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px; /* sliding doors padding */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('div#right-column-sidebar ol li:gt(9)').hide();
    $('a.button').click( function() { 
        $('div#right-column-sidebar ol li:gt(9)').toggle(); 
        $('a.button').addClass('change-height');
    });
});
```

Comment: you should move your code into a jsfiddle

Comment: Why not absolutely position your button to the bottom, so that it moves with the end of your list?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something similar to this - http://jsfiddle.net/7CxG8/ ?

I removed the `position: absolute` from the `ol` so the button became aware/responded to change of dimensions of the `ol`.

To get the "slowmotion effect" you could just pass a number as an argument of the jquerys toggle function (3000 = 3s) - it works but it's not the best effect you could get imo. I usually create my own effects with css transitions/animations.